# Could "Something has to wait" be a form of euphemism?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

> A: I'm parking right there.
>
> B: You have to wait!
>
> A: Why?
>
> B: (Pointing at the corner) That car is trying to get out.

Here, "You have to wait" feels somewhat abrupt and rude. But if you switch that to "Parking will have to wait.", could this be heard more soft and polite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here, "You have to wait" feels somewhat abrupt and rude. But if you switch that to "Parking will have to wait.", could this be heard more soft and polite?**

Ah at last a question I really appreciate about use of English and being Polite

You have to wait and Parking will have to wait are both instructions and whilst using instructions maybe OK to use when speaking to your kids or employees it is not polite when talking to adults especially ones you do not know. 
However the use of a suggestion or question as a request is polite. This coupled with please or a similar exclamation makes the request seem even more polite.

The more commonly used phrase would be "Can you wait"?

Examples 
Can you wait a minute? ......Can you please wait a minute? (use of a question)

If you wait a minute, this guy will move his car and you can get in. (use of a suggestion).

Using a suggestion can be very effective because it puts forward the action you want to achieve whilst giving the reason why the request should be complied with. The ultimate is to combine the question and the suggestion.

**Can you please wait a minute? so this guy can move his car and you can get in**